# Agrupar datos por noPoliza y folioAvisoSiniestro

Tags: flutter, isar-database

Estoy intentando agrupar el resultado de una consulta por noPoliza y folio AvisoSiniestro para que no retorne registros duplicados, estoy utilizando Isar database y flutter.

> Esta es la consulta que tengo hasta este momento, pero me marca error

```
getSiniestrosAgrupados() async {
    final isarInstance = await db;
    IsarCollection<Siniestro> siniestroCollection = isarInstance.collection<Siniestro>();
    List<Siniestro?> siniestros = await siniestroCollection.filter().group((q) => q.noPoliza).findAll();
    return siniestros;
  }
```

Espero que me puedan orientar.
Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca?